# Shopping Cart Price Rule Magento ver. 1.9.2.0

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, fedex

I'm adding `Shopping Cart` `Price Rule` from `magento backend`, and specified specific `products sku` which if added to cart it will be a `free shipping`. I'm using `FedEx` as the `default` shipping method. My problem is the `Free Shipping` option is not visible on `checkout proces`s.

I'm using `Magento ver. 1.9.2.0` .

Please help.

Thank you,
JM

Comment: Could you share your shopping cart rule here ?

Comment: @Pawan here is the screenshot. http://prntscr.com/jrvuoo

Answer (score 0):

Please check in admin panel that any shipping method are enabled or not.

**`admin -> system -> configuration -> sales -> shipping methods`**

If, any shipping method is enabled but not display on checkout.

Please check that your website are multi store. If multi store,  so please check, store wise shipping method and enable it.

You need to change the Rules according to attached screenshot:-
[image]

Than it will show on checkout page like this:-

here my Shopping Cart Price Rule is `my rulesss`

[image]

I Hope this will help you!

Comment: Only FedEx is enabled, but still Shopping Cart Price Rule not working.
Please help.

Comment: Ok will let you know, if found something.

Comment: Here is the screenshot of the FedEx set up.
http://prntscr.com/jrwo2c
And the price rule set up
http://prntscr.com/jrwoam

Comment: @JmCabugnason can you see my updated answer now.

Comment: Thank you for that, but what I want is that on Shipping Method the customer can set the method to Free Shipping.